# how to escape colon (:) in XML for XML Reader in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs

I am not able to load xml which has colon in attribute name, i am using extjs-4.2.1

my sample xml

```
<RDF>
    <Seq about="urn:productManagement:root" type="ROOT" ac:maxLevels="25">
        <li>
            <Description ac:name="name1" ac:type="type1"/>
        </li>
    </Seq>
</RDF>
```

Model for above xml

```
Ext.define('TR.model.TreeControlModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            { name: 'about', mapping:'@about'},
            { name: 'type', mapping:'li>Description@ac:type'},
           { name: "name", mapping:'li>Description@ac:name'}
        ]
});
```

I tried replacing : with | (pipe) but it didn't work for me. Need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colon is a reserved character in XML identifiers, and may be used only for binding XML Namespaces. There is no way to escape it for other purposes. You *MAY* be able to find a pre-namespaces implementation of XML which doesn't check this and lets you get away with abusing the colon character, but your documents will not be interoperable with any other code that processes XML.

See the Note in http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-common-syn, and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/

Use a different character, or properly declare the ac: namespace prefix.

Answer (score 1):

This is an EXTJS question, you need to define the namespace in the XML.

In this example

```
<RDF xmlns:ac="http://my.example.com/ac">
    <Seq about="urn:productManagement:root" type="ROOT" ac:maxLevels="25">
        <li>
            <Description ac:name="name1" ac:type="type1"/>
        </li>
    </Seq>
</RDF>
```

where I put http://my.example.com/ac as the definition of the prefix as I am not sure what it should be in your example (did you make this yourself or is it from another system?). Then EXTJS 4 (not 3 or below) allows for the use of | so this should work:

```
Ext.define('TR.model.TreeControlModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'about', mapping:'@about'},
        { name: 'type', mapping:'li>Description@ac|type'},
       { name: "name", mapping:'li>Description@ac|name'}
    ]
```

});